# Query to select a range of numbers separated by commas

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a little help writing a query to output a list of numbers separated by commas. I have a table that has three columns. Column one is called “low” and column two is called “high” the third column indicates if the range of numbers between column 1 and 2 is a consecutive range or an odd/even range (1 for consecutive 2 for odd/even). I want to output (and store in a different column in a different table) the range of numbers separated by commas for each respective low/high range. Please see examples below (the desired_result column is what I would like the output of this query to be)

```
Low      High      oe_cons      desired_result
1        5         1            1,2,3,4,5
6        10        2            6,8,10
99       102       1            99,100,101,102
150      156       2            150,152,154,156
87       91        2            87,89,91
```

My database is MS SQL Express 2012. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/135230) here. Columns containing aggregates (e.g. a list of comma-separated numbers) violate [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and will cause you no end of problems in a relational database. Explain **why** you want to store “numbers separated by commas” in a table. What will you use them for? I suspect using aggregate functions will be a better solution.

Comment: I think your best bet is a function that takes these inputs as parameters and then loops to build the string...don't bother storing it in any table and generate it using the function as needed.  These values are absolutely horrible to handle in the future...if your plan here is to leave this 'desired result' in it's own column and never touch it again, you're good.  If you plan on trying to handle this 'array list' with SQL code further down the road, you are setting yourself up for a lot of pain.

Comment: Good points made, I really dont need them stored in a table by themselves I guess. I am trying to build a URL with this range of numbers. EXAMPLE "www.mywebsite.com?c=1,2,3,4,5" I havnt decided yet If i want to store this link once built or just just output it but either way I would imagine the query to build it should be the same? Sorry I am not a dev and alot of this goes over my head. What do you think the best way to resolve would be?

Comment: There is no need for a loop here. I will put together an example of doing this with a tally table shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which  returns the string for you.

```html
create function return_op(@low int, @high int, @oe_coin int)
returns varchar(1000)
 as
 begin
declare @a varchar(3000)

set @a = ''
select @a = coalesce(@a + ',', '') + cast(n as varchar(3)) from (select n from (
  SELECT TOP 1000 n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects 
  
  ORDER BY n)a
where n between @low and @high
and (n-@low)%@oe_coin = 0 )a

return substring(@a, 2, 1000)
end
```

Then it becomes fairly simple

```html
select low, high, oe_coin, return_op(low, high, oe_coin) from Table1
```

Comment: That would work but scalar functions are notoriously poor for performance.

Comment: Good point. But if the  size of table is small(in a few thousands), then this should not matter. Otherwise, yes it would.

Comment: I disagree. You should always write code that is scalable. Just because the table is small today it might not be tomorrow. And somebody else may come along and see a scalar function and decide it must be ok and do the same thing on a several million row table. Performance should be a consideration in every line of code, not just when it is convenient. Sorry...soap box off now. :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I just tested this method but there are two issues, first its only outputing 50,52,54,56,58,60 no matter what I put in as the inputs. I can change it in the code and obviously the output changes but I dont know how to fix that for a dynamic input. second minor issue is there is a space after every comma, is that easy to remove? Also with respect to table size this procedure will only ever be executed on a few hundred records at once so i am not worried about performance but I do see Seans point.

Comment: Edited the answer..Please check again.

Comment: its unfortunately giving me this error now:  Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type varchar.   sorry for all the questions i am just not too skilled in this area.

Comment: If the range of values, i.e. difference between 'low' and 'high' is  too high, the comma separated string output might take up more than 3000 characters, in which case this error message might appear. From your example, it seemed to be not much, but nevertheless, what is the data type of the column 'desired_result' in the table? if it is say  varchar(max), set the data type of variable '@a' in the function to varchar(max) too. Hope this helps!

Comment: heres what I am trying to run:  select dbo.return_op(100, 110, 2)  the expected output of this is 100,102,104,106,108,110   and its still giving me the message. I tried to change the value to max but that did not seem to address the issue.

Comment: and actually just found another error, when I run this:  select dbo.return_op(1,13,2) go i would expect it to return all odd numbers from 1 to 13 including 1 and 13, but it only returns the even numbers.

Comment: Ok..I had used n-50 instead of n-@low(Sorry, I had not tested it on SSMS properly). Edited the answer again. Can you check once again?

Comment: its getting very close but its still dropping the first character in what it returns and some combinations are still also causing it to return the arithmetic overflow error, heres an example of one that breaks it: select dbo.return_op(100,110,1) go

Comment: Changed a few data types here and there. Its giving expected results now.

Comment: excellent, looks like its working well but its still chopping off the first character in the returned results.

Comment: Wow..this sucks! :( Last edit: since you had asked to not have space before comma, I should have changed the substring function too..which I just did

Comment: this is working well now but i just noticed that i totally typoed on my original post. for my data 1 is odd/even and 2 is consecutive numbers. is that easy to address? Also large numbers are still breaking it but thats really not that big of a deal ex: select dbo.return_op(4890,4896,1) returns nothing

Comment: Ok few questions. 1) I didn't get the part:- for my data 1 is odd/even and 2 is consecutive numbers 2) Is it possible for you to give the max value that can ever come? In my code, i am selecting values from 1 to 1000. If you think the range is say 10000, replace the TOP 1000 with TOP 10000

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this. This way does not use a scalar function and it builds the tally table using a little trick so you don't have to read a single base table instead of using any of the system tables.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

go

create table #Something
(
    SomeKey int identity,
    Low int,
    High int,
    oe_cons int
)

insert #Something
select 1, 5 , 1 union all
select 6, 10, 2 union all
select 99, 102, 1 union all
select 150, 156, 2 union all
select 87, 91, 2;

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
--I actually have the above 4 ctes as a view in my system so I can reference it at any point
--it is the fastest way possible to generate 10k rows. There is not even a single read in 
--the execution plan for it. :)
, FilteredResults as
(
    select *
    from #Something s
    join cteTally t on t.N >= s.Low and t.N <= s.High
)

select SomeKey,
    STUFF((select ',' + cast(N as varchar(4))
    from FilteredResults fr2
    where fr2.SomeKey = fr.SomeKey
        and (fr2.N + fr2.Low) % fr2.oe_cons = 0
    order by N
    for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
from FilteredResults fr
group by SomeKey
order by SomeKey
```

Comment: This actually works very well but I am having two minor issues. First I made a typo in my original post, 1 means odd/even and 2 means consecutive numbers. I couldn't figure out how to fix that. 2nd since I am not a developer at all I cant for the life of me figure out how to combine this with my current select statement (my current statement has alot more data in it than I have provided here, this was just the small part I needed help with) let me know if that makes sense or if you need more detail.

Comment: OK I get what you mean about using consecutive numbers. I don't get though what you mean by odd/even. Are you saying that you just want to increment by 2 when oe_cons = 1. So if the low value is even all the results will be even and if the low value is odd the results will all be odd? Assuming that is what you mean we can adjust the where clause to deal with that. Not quite sure what you need to have happen as far as your bigger query but I can help if you can post details about what you need there.

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER()` gets you a number sequence.  `TOP` limits it.  `','+LTRIM(STR())` makes it text. `FOR XML` concatenates. `STUFF` chops off the leading comma.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STUFF((
      SELECT TOP((a.High-a.Low)/a.oe_cons+1)
        ','+LTRIM(STR(a.Low+a.oe_cons*(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1)))
      FROM master.dbo.spt_values
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'')
) b(desired_result)
```